# Why is Photos uploading more photos than I have?

Tags: macos, photos

When I open photos it shows the number of photos and the number left to upload:

[image]

How come it is uploading more photos than I have?

Answer (score 1):

This may be caused by duplicate photos. For some reason Photo app sometimes adds already existing photos or user may import already imported ones. 
You can try Photos Duplicate Cleaner app. I haven't checked it now, but it was free a couple months ago.

Comment: Still? I moved from iPad 1 to Nexus because of that particular problem. You'd thin five years would be long enough to get things sorted out. Of course there's still no lock button on iTunes playlists, and it's been 10 years since that sacrifice to wandering cat paws got written into code.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger now, when there's a solution, you can come back:D